# Rails form_tag remove paramters from URL but pass to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to remove a parameter from the URL and be able to get the value in the controller?

I tired using

form_tag "/abc",  method: get do

hidden_field_tag :abc, "alpha", :name => nil

But after that I am not able to access the parameter in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't work with a GET request; your browser has nowhere else to put the data except the CGI parameters.

Sessions and cookies could perhaps be used, but that depends on the details of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check if you have the parameter allowed in strong params array?